# Is the orthogonal group of $\mathbb R^\infty$ contractible?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $\mathbb R^\infty$ be the direct sum of countably many copies of $\mathbb R$ topologized as the colimit over its finite dimensional subspaces. This topology should make every linear self-map of $\mathbb R^\infty$ continuous. Let $O(\mathbb R^\infty)$ be the group of linear isomorphisms $A\colon \mathbb R^\infty\to \mathbb R^\infty$ that preserve the inner product $\langle v,w\rangle=\sum_i v_iw_i$.

**Question:** Is $O(\mathbb R^\infty)$ contractible with the compact-open topology?

I believe that the answer should be yes, but I'm short of a proof. I'm aware of the following facts:

- The unit sphere $S(\mathbb R^\infty)$ is contractible (e.g. Hatcher's book, Example 1B.3 on page 88).
- The space of linear isometric embeddings $\mathbb R^\infty \to \mathbb R^\infty$ is contractible (Lewis-May-Steinberger, *Equivariant Stable Homotopy Theory*, Lemma 1.5 on page 60).
- Bott's orthogonal group $O(\infty)=\mathrm{colim}_n O(n)$ is not contractible (Bott perdiodicity).
- If $\mathcal H$ is the Hilbert space completion of $\mathbb R^\infty$, then the orthogonal group $O(\mathcal H)$ is contractible with the norm topology (Kuiper's theorem).

I'm pretty sure that there are continuous embeddings $O(\infty)\hookrightarrow O(\mathbb R^\infty) \hookrightarrow O(\mathcal H)$ non of which is surjective. I'm struggling to adapt either Hatcher's argument or the one used by Lewis-May-Steinberger to $O(\mathbb R^\infty)$. Any ideas?

Comment: (This was a reply to a comment that doesn't seem to exist anymore...) As I wrote, I think that $O(\mathbb R^\infty)$ is larger than $O(\infty)$. Take any matrix $id\ne A\in O(n)$ and form an infinite diagonal block matrix with $A$ in every diagonal entry. This should be an element of $O(\mathbb R^\infty)$ that is not contained in $O(\infty)$. I also don't know how to prove that $O(\mathbb R^\infty)$ is homotopically non-trivial. I don't think it should be, because you can actually "escape to infinity", unlike in $O(\infty)$.

Comment: Thanks, I deleted the comment because I noticed late that you mentioned the Bott theorem.  I figured out the difference already - that in the Bott space each matrix is limited to its dimension - while in the space you're talking about there's a potential for unbounded expansion of dimension.